# How do I hang curtains on a cutout like this?

Tags: hanging, curtain-rail

I have this cutout and was wondering how I would be able to hang some curtains without them looking out of place!

[image]

I was thinking putting a curtain and rod on the upper part before the cutout but wasn’t sure if there is something that can be done on the inside?

Thanks!

Comment: This is an opinion so it might be closed but if you abated to cover the opening when closed up on the header would be normal, inside underneath would how some verticals blinds hang and Venetian style but they can be outside also since you have the space and do a verticals sliding type you could park them on the right hung underneath and they would be out of the way and not blocking the window when open.  We have used different designers and some like outside and some inside underneath to me it depends on the blind or curtains.

Comment: google `net curtain wire` for a simple way to hang sheer curtains ... it is similar to the outside covering of bicycle brake cables

Comment: This is a decorating advice question, which is off-topic, but many curtain rods have been installed at or slightly below casing height to the sides. Many curtains have frills that extend above the rod for better coverage.

Comment: Thanks for all the advice! My apologies for asking a more opinion based question, I will keep that in mind for further questions :)

Comment: It's only a decorating question if you ignore its premise: *how to mount a curtain rod here* : to either the trim or the ceiling.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look into a ceiling mounted curtain rod

Answer (score 6):

Attach your brackets to the upper window molding as close to the edge as possible.

Answer (score 5):

You might consider "accordion" style folding interior shutters. They would fold up pretty flat against the adjacent walls.

Something like this:

[image]

The fact that the opening is asymmetrical would not preclude this from working. And unlike curtains when opened in such a tight space, they wouldn't block much of the window.